# How to start hugin (photostitcher program) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation

Tried installing the photostitching program **hugin** . First attempt was using synaptic package manager. It appeared to install but there was no entry in menu to be able to start the program. After checking on this forum I found a suggestion to uninstall it and reinstall using terminal. Did that, using command line  **sudo apt-get install hugin**  It appeared to install again, no errors, but there is still no entry in the menu - how do I start this program? I am relatively new to Linux so please write plain non-technical answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Hugin from deb-package. The deb-package is an archive with some [contents inside it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/hugin/filelist).

This package installs desktop-file shortcuts, so on GNOME Shell you can press <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd> key and find *Hugin Panorama Creator* here:

> [image: Hugin icons on GNOME Shell]

On GNOME Classic, Xfce, KDE or MATE it will be placed in Graphics section:

> [image: Hugin icons]

As any other application it also may be launched from terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - by executing `hugin` command.

Comment: How do I get to GNOME Shell?  How do I get Hugin to appear in the menu? I can find a whole bunch of Hugin files by searching in the File system, so it is installed, but which file do I run to put Hugin in the menu?

Comment: On my clean fresh 18.04 LTS it is in place - see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTJou.png).

Comment: I do not get these icons on my desktop at all. Searching in File System finds dozens of hugin items. So again I ask, How do I get an icon on my desktop or in the menu so I can use hugin? I have removed and reinstalled this package several times and it makes no difference.

Comment: How do I add a screenshot to show you what installed?  Program appears to run using terminal to launch it, but it is supposed to have an icon to click to run.  @NOrbert - reply